# How to delete locked files?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I want to delete files that are locked by a process. The files should be deleted and right after that recreated, so the MoveFileEx function would not be a solution. Does anybody know a way to do that ? I've searched the internet, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's an awful generalisation, and I would generalise otherwise that it is mostly a terrible recommendation. Imagine backup software killing a user's Outlook process to access the PST. Then abstract it to be any user software. Insane.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's about doing it when the software is active that is particularly dangerous in that instant. I'm not talking about how you might handle it when not locked - that's an engineering decision that should be thought out on a per requirement basis, which demands different line of questioning, and gets out of scope - this doesn't diminish the principle that your advice is potentially dangerous (and exhibits an attitude that scares me).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Exactly, in certain circumstances, hence my 'bad generalisation' statement.

Comment: I bet that you just forgot to call  `Dispose` on your file objects. You should consider the `using` statement.

Comment: I bet that happened too, but I cannot modify that piece of code, and probably should not be modified, because for some reason it will make the analysis much slower.

Comment: In due course you will realise that you need to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

Unlock the file ? ( End the process that is locking it )

There's a program called Unlocker ( from sysinternal ) that can unlock a locked file, but you might run to trouble: http://forum.sysinternals.com/how-to-unlock-a-file_topic7980.html

You can also check out this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/9e2044c5-ae5d-4552-a335-01cc567dfc58

Comment: I should unlock it automatically through c# code. And I also cannot end the process.

Comment: The the purpose of locking a file is because it must not be modified until the process has completed to do what he need to do ( and that's why it locks the file )

Comment: I understand that, but in the current case I want to force an unlock of that files.

Comment: Check the last link of my answer, the post with "In order to unlock a file used by another process you should run code in the context of that process and do a CloseHandle on the specific handle."

Comment: @FMaz008 Or to lock down the file 'just because', a la Outlook.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I get your point, but the solution will be risky, I didn't want to recommand CreateRemoteThread stuff without proper warnings&reading.

Comment: What if the process that is locking this file is my process ? Is it possible to release the handle if I know the file name ? The code that is locking the file is not available to me and it cannot be modified. Is it possible to get the handle for file and then release it ?

Comment: @user1202034 When you do that the other code that is still trying to access the file will fail. Quite possibly catastrophically. What you are trying to do sounds like the wrong solution to the problem. You didn't actually tell us the problem so there's not a lot we can do to help.

Comment: @user1202034 As mentioned in the last link of my anwser: "In order to unlock a file used by another process you should run code in the context of that process and do a CloseHandle on the specific handle."

Comment: Ok, I am building an application. I have a file structure. I can delete folder/file, create folder/file. When I create folder ( and some files in it ) my code executes some referenced code which performs some basic analysis of that folder. During this analysis, some files are generated by the analysis in my folder. After I close the folder, I am calling a method which stops that analysis and all the actions related to it. Unfortunately the analysis still holds handles to the files that has generated, even though it doesn't actually need them.

Comment: Then when I try to delete my folder, I receive an exception. So my target here is to unlock the generated files, which are locked by my process and delete them. I have read your suggestion, but I don't actually understand how to get the handle for the generated files.